# Report email as spam?

Tags: email, gmail

Is it possible to report an email as spam? I cannot see an option to do this with a Gmail account, is it possible with other account types?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For Gmail, don't you just move it to the "Spam" folder? This is what I have always done, and assumed it works.

Comment: You are correct. I am used to seeing a "report as spam" button and not working with folders.

Comment: The same applies to Hotmail and Exchange Online on Office 365, but I cannot positively say if it gets reported as spam that way.